# Getting typeError when trying to convert r dataframe to json with rpy2

Tags: python, r, dataframe, rpy2, bioconductor

```python
import json
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

biocPkgTools = importr('BiocPkgTools')
biocPkgList = biocPkgTools.biocPkgList()
biocPkgList = json.loads(ro.conversion.rpy2py(biocPkgList))
```

The dataframe looks great and I'm just trying to convert it to a json object with column names as keys but I receive this error:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bioconductor/bioconductor.py", line 11, in <module>
    json = json.loads(ro.conversion.rpy2py(biocPkgList))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not DataFrame
```

Other steps I've tried is converting it to a pandas dataframe then to json but that also gives an error. I appreciate any help I can get.

Pandas method:

```python
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri as rpyn
import json
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro


biocPkgTools = importr('BiocPkgTools')
biocPkgList = biocPkgTools.biocPkgList()
columns = list(biocPkgList.colnames)
biocPkgList_df = pd.DataFrame(biocPkgList)
biocPkgList_df = biocPkgList_df.T
biocPkgList_df.columns = columns
biocPkgList_json = biocPkgList_df.to_json(orient='records')
print(biocPkgList_json)
```

I get these R errors:

```
R[write to console]: Error: unimplemented type 'char' in 'eval'

R[write to console]: Error: cannot have attributes on a CHARSXP

R[write to console]: Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT
```

Comment: Please post the code where you tried to convert the R dataframe to pandas, and then to JSON, along with the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: @MattDMo just updated for you, the dataframe looks good after adding the columns (I lose these for whatever reason when converting to pandas) but when I try to convert it to json is where it errors.

Comment: Are there any Python errors for the pandas method, or just R? Do you know what line triggers the error?

Comment: No these are the only lines my console shows after running the file.

Comment: Well, the good(?) news is that I can replicate your error on my Mac, even when calling `to_json()` without arguments. The bad news is that the error is, shall we say, less than helpful at pointing out the actual problem. I was able to find [this issue](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/773) on Github, perhaps you could try the suggestion in the [last comment](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/773#issuecomment-814971929) and see if that works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an R DataFrame to JSON-formatted Python dict/list structure (which seem to be what you are attempting), you need to either:

- (a) convert it to JSON string in R and then parse the JSON string in Python
- (b) convert it to pandas DataFrame and then covert that to JSON

For the solution (a), I would recommend using `rjson` R package:

```py
import json
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
bioc_pkg_tools = importr('BiocPkgTools')
rjson = importr('rjson')

bioc_pkg_data_frame = bioc_pkg_tools.biocPkgList()
r_json_string_vector = rjson.toJSON(bioc_pkg_data_frame)
py_json_string = r_json_string_vector[0]
py_json_structure = json.loads(py_json_string)
print(py_json_structure.keys())
# dict_keys(['Package', 'Version', 'Depends', 'Suggests', 'License', 'MD5sum', 'NeedsCompilation', 'Title', 'Description', 'biocViews', 'Author', 'Maintainer', 'git_url', 'git_branch', 'git_last_commit', 'git_last_commit_date', 'Date/Publication', 'source.ver', 'win.binary.ver', 'mac.binary.ver', 'vignettes', 'vignetteTitles', 'hasREADME', 'hasNEWS', 'hasINSTALL', 'hasLICENSE', 'Rfiles', 'dependencyCount', 'Imports', 'Enhances', 'dependsOnMe', 'VignetteBuilder', 'suggestsMe', 'LinkingTo', 'Archs', 'URL', 'SystemRequirements', 'BugReports', 'importsMe', 'PackageStatus', 'Video', 'linksToMe', 'License_restricts_use', 'organism', 'OS_type', 'License_is_FOSS'])
```

Now, as for (b) the code would be along these lines:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects import default_converter
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter, rpy2py
base = importr('base')

with localconverter(default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    pandas_dataframe = base.as_data_frame(bioc_pkg_data_frame)

py_json_string = pandas_dataframe.to_json()
py_json_structure = json.loads(py_json_structure)
```

However, it does not work in this case (raising  `TypeError: 'NULLType' object is not iterable`), because the R data frame contains lists (e.g. in  the `Depends` column) and conversion of data frames with embedded lists is not yet supported by rpy2 (https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/773 and https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/860).

You can still extract a subset of the data frame that does not include list:

```py
list_columns = []
i = 1
columns_to_keep = []

for column_name in bioc_pkg_data_frame.names:
    # rx2 is equivalent of `bioc_pkg_data_frame[[column_name]]` in R
    column = bioc_pkg_data_frame.rx2(column_name)
    r_class = get_r_class(column)[0]
    if r_class == 'list':
        list_columns.append(column_name)
    else:
        columns_to_keep.append(i)
    i += 1

# we will exclude these:
print(list_columns)
# Depends, Suggests, biocViews, Author, Maintainer, vignettes, vignetteTitles, Rfiles, Imports, Enhances, dependsOnMe, suggestsMe, LinkingTo, Archs, importsMe, linksToMe
```

And then get a pandas dataframe and JSON (string/structure) with:

```py
with localconverter(default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    pandas_dataframe = base.as_data_frame(bioc_pkg_data_frame_no_lists)

py_json_string = pandas_dataframe.to_json()
py_json_structure = json.loads(py_json_structure)
```

(or you could convert the lists to a concatenated string)